# Access text field value in block

Tags: magento-1.8, blocks

I am new in magento extension development .

How i access street value in edit.phtml of 'id=street_1' textfeild in Edit block .

Please give me suggestion in detail.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide more details? You are trying to access it via js, via php, via anything else?

Comment: I access it in Edit.php via php.

Answer (score 1):

You can access it in `_prepareLayout`  from the `Edit.php` block like this.

```
$value = $this->_address->getStreet(1);
```

**EDIT**-based on comments

You can access the address before saving it in `Mage_Customer_AddressController::formPostAction` with

```
$street = $this->getRequest()->getPost('street'); 
$part1 = $street[0];
```

To access/modify/validate the address before saving it use the event `customer_address_save_before`.

Comment: yes you are right but it give me database value right?but I want current textbox value which is not saved in database but user type in textbox .it is possible?

Comment: You cannot access that in the edit.php file. You can access it after the user submits the form. In `Mage_Customer_AddressController::formPostAction` with `$street = $this->getRequest()->getPost('street'); $part1 = $street[0];`

Comment: Thanks Marius.can u tell me is any other way to access it before saving?

Comment: I think it's better if you explain in the question what are you trying to achieve. The question is a bit unclear. There are multiple ways to access that value. Observe events, directly in controller like I explained, ... In order to give you the best method I need to know what you want to do with it.

Comment: simple i just want before saving address in database first it access in Edit.block my custom method then i check whether it is correct or not if it is incorrect then i will correct it and change textfeild value of Edit.phtml and then save it.It is possile ?Logic of correctness are redy but i have to problen in access value of textfeild before saving.will you help me please.

Comment: Observe the event `customer_address_save_before`. You should be able to access the address object and modify the street value.

Comment: @user64375 you seems to want to do validations to that field before submitting the form. if it is so, do it in javascript file i.e at client side.

Comment: @Marius maybe you can update your answer

Comment: @DavidManners. Done.